# "A data source must be bound before this operation can be performed"

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, razor

I am trying to display a grid in the MVC 3, 
I got the following error:

**A data source must be bound before this operation can be performed.**

**this is my Model:**

```
   public class EmpModel
    {
        public string UserName { get; set; }
        public string Password { get; set; }
        public int EmpID { get; set; }
        public string EName { get; set; }
        public int Age { get; set; }
        public string Gender { get; set; }
        public string Qualification { get; set; }
        public string Address { get; set; }
        public string EmailID { get; set; }
        public int DeptID { get; set; }
        public string DeptName { get; set; }
        public string DeptHead { get; set; }
        public int Deptnumber { get; set; }
    }
```

**This is Controller:**

```
TestMVCEntities testEmp = new TestMVCEntities();
EmpModel empmod = new EmpModel();
public ActionResult Index()
{
    List<EmpModel> emp = new List<EmpModel>();
    return View();
}
```

**This is my View:**

```
@model IEnumerable<EmpApplication.Models.EmpModel>
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Index";
    WebGrid grid = new WebGrid();
}

<h2>List of Employee</h2>

@grid.GetHtml(columns: new [] {
    grid.Column("EmpID"),
    grid.Column("EName"),
    grid.Column("EmailID"),
    grid.Column("Qualification")
})
```

Comment: where exactly are you getting the error?

Comment: @DmitryK I am getting the following error: A data source must be bound before this operation can be performed.

Comment: don't u need to send the model to the view too. `return View(emp);` and bind the data to the grid?

Comment: @Verkion I did that but I am getting the same error

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You must pass as parameter the `source` of your data. The WebGrid expects a `IEnumerable<Object>` or `IEnumerable<dynamic>` as `source`.

You must return the list to your view:

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    List<EmpModel> emp = new List<EmpModel>();

    return View(emp);
}
```

Then pass it to WebGrid constructor:

```
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Index";
    WebGrid grid = new WebGrid(Model);;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but I did not got any records on the page.

Comment: @Raj that is because you don't fetch any... You are only creating an empty collection and passing it to the view. You need to fill it with your data

Comment: @Verkion How to fill the data? can you please tell me more about it

Comment: @Raj that's a new question.. But start with using your `testEmp`, if it is your `dbcontext`, to get all your employees

Answer (score 0):

I'm sure it's works..

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
List<EmpModel> emp = new List<EmpModel>();
return View(emp.AsEnumerable());
}
```

You just change your retrun list as `enumerable`.